# How can I avoid NullReferenceException when setting the DataSource of a listBox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to add the following code to my form:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("1");
list.Add("2");
list.Add("3");
list.Sort();
listBox5.DataSource = list;
```

Upon attempting to run the code, I get an error:

> "NullReferenceException was unhandled: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object."

How can I fix this?

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: Thank you very much Brian. This is my first post on this site and I had tried editing it myself to fix it, but it would not allow me as you had already done so. Very quick! The line causing the error is line 6.

Comment: are you sure yuo get that exception there? I cant see any null reference there

Comment: listBox5 looks null, the list is certainly not

Comment: there must be an error somewhere else in your code because there is nothing wrong with the code there at least up to the `list.Sort()` it works well

Comment: Yes, this is the line that causes the error. If I try showing the list using MessageBox, everything works fine. if I try using this code in a console project, and using Console.Writeline, it works fine. I just can't put it into a listBox, or textBox, or seemingly any Windows Form display

Comment: Knowing where in the code (posting the entire stack) can be helpful. sometimes, internal code can do this; but from looking at the objects in play, it should work OK.  Is this windows forms or ASP.NET?

Comment: here's a quick way to determine if the `listBox5` exist open the Designer.cs file and do find and see if `listBox5` exist

Comment: Are you running this code in the Form's constructor? If so, are you running it before or after `InitializeComponent();`?

Comment: Do you have any event handlers hooked up to the ListBox?

Comment: rshepp, I had mistakenly put this code before InitializeComponent();. Silly that I didn't see this. Thank you. How do I mark this as solved, and mark this as the top answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably placed this code in the forms constructor, before `InitializeComponent()` was called.
Code that references form objects should always be placed after `InitializeComponent()`

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you'll get that is because your listbox does not exist.
Your list setting is ok.

Make sure your control exists and it's the right one.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely the right listBox name, also if I try it in a textBox, the textBox name has been verified to be correct numerous times, as I thought this might be the issue as well. To verify there is not an issue elsewhere, I'm going to make a new, empty form, create a listBox, and try in there.

Comment: are you using winforms or wpf ?